# How to locate Gemfile or bundle after "Heroku local -f Procfile.dev" commend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-cli

I am following the instruction from Heroku's blog article: https://blog.heroku.com/a-rock-solid-modern-web-stack, and at the section, where I need to set up Procfile.dev" for Heroku.

The file needs to be place at the root of the application where my "client" (React Web Front) and "api" (Rails API backend) folders are. So, when I insert command:

"heroku local -f Procfile.dev"

The error indicates the following:

```
10:00:56 PM web.1 |  yarn run v1.9.4
10:00:56 PM api.1 |  Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
10:00:56 PM api.1 Exited with exit code null
10:00:56 PM web.1 Exited with exit code
```

"

It states that it cannot find my Gemfile, which is located inside the API folder. So, I like to ask "How to locate Gemfile or bundle after "Heroku local -f Procfile.dev" commend"???

Thanks

Comment: `Procfile` should be in the root of `rails application`, at the same level as `Gemfile`.

Comment: If I change the Procfile.dev directory under the rails app ('api'), then it will throw me an error, stating that it cannot find my 'client'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change directories to your app, THEN run bundle install :)

Comment: Thank you. I think it's working now. I put my 'client' folder under my 'api' and moved Procfile.dev under my 'api".  Yeah..  Thank you. So, here is my folder structure:  ProjectFolder > API  (Procfile.dev is moved in here) > Client.